# Making a facebook notification system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications

I am working on asp.net mvc 5 project, i really need healp on how to make a notification system just like facebook (whnever a user posted a record the orher users will be notified) any healp?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this. It might help you

http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/create-a-facebook-like-notifications-using-jquery-css.htm

But the solution provided is only for front-end, you need to tune your database structure to create alerts based on the user interaction with the website